# Move a file after changing the format

Tags: python, string, split, move

I have a code that I use widely for separating and moving files around daily. However, my current problem is not being able to differenciate between different formats and make them move together.

For example this is the code I want to use for moving two files named ; 
`xenian13.kat` and `xenian13_tuy.rap`

```
 import os
 import shutil
 import glob


 a = xenian13.kat
 shutil.move(a, '/home/cad/')
 b = os.path.splitex(a) + '_tuy.rap'
 shutil.move(b, '/home/cad/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.splitext` returns tuple like `("file_name", ".ext")`.

- Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

So if you want to get `xenian13_tuy.rap` from `xenian13.kat`, you need to write your code like below.

```
b = os.path.splitext(a)[0] + '_tuy.rap'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed the vital point of using this line. Thanks for the reference too!